# How to place image items retrieved in for loop side by side in bootstrap?

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-5

I am trying to build a page where pig profiles are retrieved from the db and the breed and picture are displayed ,2 profiles per row, side by side but cannot figure out how to stop them just each appearing on a new row. The profiles are retrieved fine and each one looks how I would like and links to the individual page but they are always on seperate rows.

I have tried placing a container before the for loop but I can't figure out the logic of getting them beside each other.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<br/>
<div class="container text-center"
    <div class="row">
        <h1> Pig Breeds </h1>
    </div>
</div><br/>



        {% for pig in pigs %}


        <div class="container text-center">
        
            <div class="col col-sm-4">
                
                        
                        
                    <div class="row">
                        <a href="{{ url_for('pig_page', id=pig.id)}}"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + pig.breed_picture)}}"" class="rounded-circle"  height='200'></a>
                    </div><br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h2><a href="{{ url_for('pig_page', id=pig.id)}}">{{ pig.breed }}<a/></h2>
                    </div>
                    
                        {% if current_user.id == 1 %}
                            <a href="{{ url_for('delete_pig', id=pig.id) }}" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><br/><br/>
        </div>
  

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same column width across all entries, you can already define the number of columns when [defining the rows](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#row-columns).
The following example defines a one-column layout for a small display, and a two-column layout for a medium-sized display.

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 g-4">
    {% for pig in pigs -%}
    <div class="col">
        <!-- Your content here. -->
    </div>
    {% endfor -%}
</div>
```

Make sure that open tags are properly closed again. This is not the case with the second anchor.